# how to use Arraylist (for-loop) in Jfreechart piechart?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, jfreechart, pie-chart

i recently started on collecting data in my Database, i wrote a code that retrieves this information, name(language) and the amount of times this language has been counted, into an arraylist. from this data i wanted to make a Piechart.

i have tried to do this with jfreechart

does anyone know how to use the data in my arraylist with the piechart createdataset code from jfreechart , since my attempts resulted in failure(empty piechart) while using a for loop in the the method ,createdataset, since the data in the arraylist changes and therefore dont want to hardcode the values and names.

for loop attempt(everything else left default):

```
public PieDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
    for(Language l: languageList){
    result.setValue( l.getName(), l.getCount());
    }
    return result;
}
```

if this for loop is possible what am i doing wrong or what has to change tom make this work, if i'm completely off i also want to know.

--edit--

```
public PieDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
    int count = 0;
    for(Language l: languageList){
        result.insertValue(count++, l.getName(), l.getCount());

    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [insertValue](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/DefaultPieDataset.html#insertValue-int-java.lang.Comparable-double-) api like:

```
int count = 0;
for(Language l: languageList){
    result.insertValue(count++, l.getName(), l.getCount());
}
```

Comment: i tried it like that(except for the semicolon next to count++ ), and also with making it count and after the settter making it increment,still empty piechart,tho i have data

Comment: without the for loop and hardcoded places and values it does work,so it is something with the use of the for loop i believe

Comment: I doubt, can you share your modified code in your question?

Comment: So what's the issue now? Do you have name and count? Can you print before inserting the value to data set?

Comment: i can, i can also show you the output of the print, practically the same as this loop, only it includes the System.out println for the writing

Comment: the problem is that when i run the pie it gives an empty window,wich is only when using t he for loop,using default values works but setting them with the forloop doesnt

Comment: @ricardospek: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Comment: i would like to give it all but certain aprts are accesing the databse and the database is also need for the values,wich would result in no use. the data is in the arraylist al i need is a way to set it as the values without hardcoding it